# Vue + Bulma In custom Component

Tags: vue.js, sass, components, overriding, bulma

I'm creating a custom Vue2 + Bulma component. It works fine by its own in its own project. But when I add it to a different project, I have collisions with the SCSS variables.

Here is the scenario:

- I have the component in its own project. It has a lot of custom SCSS on top of Bulma.
- In the component I am importing the bulma variables:

> @import '~bulma/sass/utilities/_all';

- I am using in my template classes like 'is-primary'. In other places I am changing the color of borders or backgrounds using the $primary variable.
- In my main project, after importing the component, it works fine as expected.
- I have a custom SCSS in the main project, in which I override the default Bulma variables to different colors, eg: $primary -> purple.
- Then the component behaves like this: for all the is-primary and similar classes, the new color is shown. For all the SCSS rules that I have created using $primary, they all have the default Bulma primary color: $turquoise.

This happens in both, dev and prod builds.
Any ideas to fix this? Without having to change all the variables to static colors, overriding rules from the main project or using generic Bulma classes instead of specific SCSS rules.

[Bulma colors issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik3AY.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your key problem is that your SCSS variables are not being loaded in the per-component builds. If you're building using webpack and vue-loader probably the best solution is to set up your default variables as a 'global' piece of scss that gets loaded for every compilation. See https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sharing-global-variables

If for example, your variables are in `src/_variables.scss` your config would look something like:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: '@import "src/variables.scss";'
      }
    }
  }
}
```